# How to rename all the files in a folder in Visual Studio forms?

Tags: forms, file, visual-studio-2012, replace, directory

for example:

I have a folder which contains 20 files with name xyz_CR7.rpt and I want to rename the file part _CR7 to _CR10. 
It happens on the click of save button using save file dialog box.

code:

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) <br/>
{<br/>
saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";<br/>
saveFileDialog1.Title = "Enter Location";<br/>
saveFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;<br/>
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";      <br/>           
saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;<br/>
saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;<br/>
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)<br/>
{<br/>
string filename = saveFileDialog1.FileName;<br/>
comboBox2.Text = saveFileDialog1.FileName;<br/>
foreach (string file inDirectory.EnumerateFiles(comboBox1.Text,"*_C7.rpt"))<br/>
   {<br/>
    string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);<br/>
    String S1 = "_C7";<br/>
    String S2 = "_C10";<br/>
       if (comboBox1.Text.Contains(S1))<br/>
          {<br/>
          S1 = S2;<br/>

    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Try a google search. Questions like yours are unlikely to get response, because you are basically saying "I have no idea how to do this, please write some code for me", but on StackOverflow it is better to ask what is wrong with your own code, after providing what you have authored since now.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm New here

Comment: Code added and working of this code is to save the file name with new name on click of save button

Comment: You have not to change the value of the suffix, but the file name, by means of a "replace" operation on its string value, then you have to rename the file with that value, what encompasses calling a suitable method for that: it will update the filename on the filesystem. To sum up, you have to perform two operations: change the filename string and use it to rename the file on the filesystem.

Comment: I'll try this and let u know  Thank you